# AWS Configuration with Autofac

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, autofac

I am using Autofac and want to configure AmazonSimpleEmailService.
I am looking for the equivalent of

```
services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(_configuration.GetAWSOptions());
services.AddAWSService<IAmazonSimpleEmailService>();
```

So far, I tried the code below, however I could not yet solved Parameter part.

```
builder.Register(c => _configuration.GetAWSOptions()); <<-- I dont think it will work.
builder.RegisterType<AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient>() 
    .As<IAmazonSimpleEmailService>()
    .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(AmazonSimpleEmailServiceConfig), ))
```

Is there an easy way of declaring this?

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?  Is there a reason you need to explicitly specify the typed parameter in the 2nd option?

Comment: @mclark1129 Nah, above code doesn't look correct.

Comment: Try something like `services.AddSingleton<IAmzonSimpleEmailService>(() => new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceEmailClient(_configuration.GetAWSOptions());`

Comment: This is not related with autofac. I am looking for adopting it to Autofac registration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the source code, that can be found [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/extensions/src/AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs), you have to do the following:

As a replacement for this line
`services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(_configuration.GetAWSOptions());`

You can do this with `Autofac`:

```cs
builder.Register(_ => _configuration.GetAWSOptions())
    .As<AwsOptions>() // or just .AsSelf()!
    .SingleInstance(); // services.Add(someServiceDescriptor) adds items as singleton by default as well
```

Now for the second part, you will need that `AWSOptions` that you've registered previously.

```cs
builder.Register(componentContext =>
    {
        var options = componentContext.Resolve<AWSOptions>();
        var client = options.CreateServiceClient<AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient>();
        return client;
    })
    .As<IAmazonSimpleEmailService>()
    .SingleInstance(); // you could choose a different scope here but there extension also defaults to singleton
```

There is no simpler way for that and this is kind of the same thing that [they do](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/2d747530644b2f7b4d14421ac3f4caafb7b268ed/extensions/src/AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L105) as well.